# what is wrong with this function??i am getting this error "encountered the symbol '(' when expecting one of the following .% @ ;.............continue

Tags: oracle, plsql

what is wrong with this function??

```
SQL> create or replace function erwin
 return number<12>;
  is
  horse number<12>;
  begin
    select sal into horse
    from emp where empno='7900';
    return horse;
  end;
  /
```

I am getting this error

> encountered the symbol '(' when expecting one of the following .% @ ;…continue

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS99897

Answer (score 0):

The [syntax is incorrect](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm):

- There should not be a `;` after the `RETURN` clause.
- The return type should be `NUMBER` (without precision or scale) not `NUMBER<12>`
- The declaration for the `horse` variable should be `NUMBER(12)` not `NUMBER<12>`.

Like this:

```
create or replace function erwin
return number
is
  horse number(12);
begin
  select sal into horse
  from emp where empno='7900';
  return horse;
end;
/
```